# Use a list in a list of lists as argument in a function call

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to call a function with parameter from a list of list, the problem is that it sees the whole list as one single argument, even though each list in the list of lists contains 3 arguments.
How do I get the function to see the list as 3 arguments

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [2, 5, 8]]


def do_something(x, y, z):
    bla. bla. bla

do_something(lists[1])
```

and the error message says so:

```
TypeError: do_something() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

Comment: The function receives 3 arguments x,y,z you are only passing 1.

Comment: explore the usage of *args, may be this is what you are looking for

Comment: you should call your method like this; do_something(list[1][0], list[1][1], list[1][2])